# how to solve unsatisfied link error when two dependencies use FFmpeg

Tags: android, gradle, ffmpeg

In my Android app I'm using Amplituda https://github.com/lincollincol/Amplituda and video trimmer https://github.com/a914-gowtham/android-video-trimmer
they both use FFmpeg which causes this error

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'lib/x86/libavcodec.so' from inputs ...

I tried to use pick first in my build.gradle

> pickFirst 'lib/x86/libavcodec.so' and then gradlew clean

the project builds fine but gives a runtime error whenever I try to trim the video

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "avpriv_init_elbg" referenced by ... ==/lib/x86/libavfilter.so"

Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in `implementation 'com.github.lincollincol:Amplituda:v2.1.5'`